# PHP Simple HTML Dom not parsing certain links

Tags: php, html, curl, simple-html-dom

I am in the process of understanding HTML DOM Parsers and how it works. I have a roadblock where I am unable to parse the following link but I am able to parse the root domain and other websites. Could someone help me understand why I am unable to parse this particular  link?

```
<?php

include('simple_html_dom.php');

$base = 'http://www.stupidstudios.com/samsung-galaxy-s6/p/bbuynow';

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $base);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $base);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$str = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$html_base = new simple_html_dom();
$html_base->load($str);

foreach($html_base->find('h1') as $element) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r( $element );
   echo "</pre>";
}

$html_base->clear(); 
unset($html_base);

?>
```

Comment: Does it give an error?

Comment: No. I think the link is not being parsed. If I try a different link from a different website it works. I am just curious what is that make this link different.

Comment: If you try to echo $str, you will get interesting result, maybe it could help, not sure...

Comment: Indeed. it is throwing an HTTP error! HTTP ERROR: 500

`Problem accessing /p. Reason:

    Server Error
Powered by Jetty://` However I have no idea what is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work when you add/spoof it with a browser agent:

```
$base = 'http://www.flipkart.com/samsung-galaxy-s6/p/itme5z4aypvtrxmy';

$curl = curl_init($base);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$str = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

echo $str;
```

Comment: Great finding! Could you please explain why that happens?

Comment: @GirishKumarKaitholil it just means they block request when the browser agent isn't found, they just response with an error 500

Comment: @GirishKumarKaitholil other than that actually, the rest of your codes work after that point, just make sure you always add/set this option.